# Getting "Template could not be loaded" error when I use Rails app generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, generator

I was following [this Rails guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#application-templates) and came across this line:

```
$ rails new thud -m https://gist.github.com/722911.txt
```

When I tried running this in my commanline, I got an error message:

> The template [/Users/newuser/Dropbox/Xperiments/Ruby/https:/gist.github.com/722911.txt] could not be loaded. Error: Could not find "/Users/newuser/Dropbox/Xperiments/Ruby/https:/gist.github.com/722911.txt" in any of your source paths. 
>   Your current source paths are: 
>   /Users/newuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@musicsite/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates

Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: It works for me. From the error, it looks like you may have missed a forward slash in the url after the protocol?

Comment: The forward slash is there in my input. It seems as though Rails is looking for the template locally for some reason. Which version of Rails are you running if I may ask?

Comment: Gotcha. It was a bug in version 3.0.3. Thanks.

Comment: If you like, you can reply with an answer and I'll accept it as correct.

Comment: As you've found, it works in 3.0.5 :)